# Using Python logger within context manager function

Tags: python, logging

I'm new to python and have gotten stuck with this issue, running Python 3.6. Within my main script, I'm trying to run a logger, but I have been unable to get the logger to work properly inside of another (context manager) function. It works fine outside of the function, however.

```
import logging
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os

# Use log for debugging
log = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s - %(levelname)s - %(asctime)s')

# Prevent duplicate logs
if (log.hasHandlers()):
    log.handlers.clear()

fh = logging.FileHandler('csv_compiler_errors.txt')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(fh)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(ch)


# Create contextmanager function 

@contextmanager
def change_dir(newdir):
    log = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
    prevdir = os.getcwd()
    try:
        yield os.chdir(os.path.expanduser(newdir))
    finally:
        os.chdir(prevdir)
        log.info("Last directory used: ", newdir)
        log.info("Returned to directory: ", os.getcwd())

with change_dir(os.getcwd()):
    print('test script')

log.info('the logger works outside of the function')
```

This is the rather lengthy error returned:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 925, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 664, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 369, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "C:/Python/csvcompiler/venv/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    print('test script')
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:/Python/csvcompiler/venv/test.py", line 35, in change_dir
    log.info("Last directory used: ", newdir)
Message: 'Last directory used: '
Arguments: ('C:\\Python\\csvcompiler\\venv',)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 925, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 664, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 369, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "C:/Python/csvcompiler/venv/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    print('test script')
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:/Python/csvcompiler/venv/test.py", line 35, in change_dir
    log.info("Last directory used: ", newdir)
Message: 'Last directory used: '
Arguments: ('C:\\Python\\csvcompiler\\venv',)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 925, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 664, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 369, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "C:/Python/csvcompiler/venv/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    print('test script')
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:/Python/csvcompiler/venv/test.py", line 36, in change_dir
    log.info("Returned to directory: ", os.getcwd())
Message: 'Returned to directory: '
Arguments: ('C:\\Python\\csvcompiler\\venv',)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 925, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 664, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 369, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "C:/Python/csvcompiler/venv/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    print('test script')
  File "C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:/Python/csvcompiler/venv/test.py", line 36, in change_dir
    log.info("Returned to directory: ", os.getcwd())
```

Do you have any advice or guidance for my situation? Thank you very much.

Comment: The context manager has nothing to do with the problem. Look at the arguments you're passing to `log.info` when it works, and when it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out. I see now the error lied in the argument structure. Changing `log.info("Last directory used: %s", newdir)` to `log.info("Last directory used: %s" % newdir)` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The failure stems not from where it's placed but how the logging methods are being called.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('demo')
>>> logger.warning('the logger works outside of the function')
the logger works outside of the function
>>> logger.warning('the logger works outside of the function', 123)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 992, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 838, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 575, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 338, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Message: 'the logger works outside of the function'
Arguments: (123,)
```

I can see that you are trying to record the additional argument - the message string must contain the tokens for which these arguments be replaced with.  For my example I am just going to use `%d` to denote an integer (`%s` will denote a string replacement, this is part of the standard format styles - refer to [logging variable data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-variable-data))

```
>>> logger.warning('the logger works outside of the function (%d)', 123)
the logger works outside of the function (123)
```

For your use case, just place a `%s` at the end to denote the place where `newline` and `os.getcwd()` will be placed.

```
        log.info("Last directory used: %s", newdir)
        log.info("Returned to directory: %s", os.getcwd())
```